# Pyspark group by aggregate in single column

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with multiple rows that should be joined into a single row. with the other info combined in a column.
Currently I can do this with collect_list and to_json.
But what I would want to do, is not have this as a list, but have it as a single column with the dictionaries in there.

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 2, "Pete","blue"), (2, 3, "John", "red"), (1, 4, "Sarah", "green")
], ("id", "numbers","names","color"))
```

And then I collect and to_json:

```
df1 = (
        df1.withColumn(
            "json",
            sf.to_json(
                sf.struct(
                    "numbers",
                    "names",
                    "color",
                )
            ),
        )
        .groupby(
            "id",
        )
        .agg(sf.collect_list("json").alias("additional_data"))
    )
```

Now this gives me:

| id | additional_data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"numbers":4,"names":"Sarah","color":"green"}, {"numbers":2,"names":"Pete","color":"blue"}] |
| 2 | [{"numbers":3,"names":"John","color":"red"}] |

But what I'd like to have is the following:

| id | additional_data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"numbers_1":4,"names_1":"Sarah","color_1":"green", "numbers_2":2,"names_2":"Pete","color_2":"blue"} |
| 2 | {"numbers":3,"names":"John","color":"red"} |

I've got a UDF that can loop the list and return a single dict, but it returns an invalid format.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
import json, ast
def unpack_dict(entries):
    d = {}
    for idx, val in enumerate(entries):
        aa = json.loads(val)
        res = {'"' + str(key) + "_" + str(idx) +'"': '"' + str(value) + '"' for key, value in aa.items()}
        d.update(res)
    return d

from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
my_udf = udf(lambda z: unpack_dict(z), StringType())
```

This outputs:

```
example = df.withColumn("combined", my_udf("additional_data")).toPandas()
```

| id | combined |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"numbers_1"="4","names_1"="Sarah","color_1"="green", "numbers_2"="2","names_2"="Pete","color_2"="blue"} |
| 2 | {"numbers"="3","names"="John","color"="red"} |

For some reason it uses = instead of : in these dict creations...

Would it be possible to make that collect_list automatically achieve the above and in the right format?
I'm open to any suggestions that can output a non nested dict as explained above.
Hope that this is clear

**UPDATE**

I changed the UDF definition to be

```
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType, StringType
my_udf = udf(lambda z: unpack_dict(z), Maptype(StringType(), StringType()))
```

And the internal function to

```
def unpack_dict(entries):
    d = {}
    for idx, val in enumerate(entries):
        dict = ast.literal_eval(val)
        result = {str(key) + "_" + str(idx): value for key, value in dict.items()}
        d.update(result)
    return d
```

This gave me the required results for a valid JSON and also solved the problem at the same time with the "=" instead of ":", meaning that I now have a valid JSON that I can use.

Comment: I solved this by changing the udf definition to the following:
```my_udf = udf(lambda z: unpack_dict(z), Maptype(StringType(), StringType()))```
and changing the function itself to remove all the ugly "'" bits

Comment: please consider posting an answer to this question to show what worked for future readers..!!

Comment: @anky Updated the original post with the working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the question with the solution that worked for me.

Comment: Your answer is not a stackoverflow valid answer. You should comment your topic to give feedback but an answer need to be a technical answer